How to Create a Service Account with Minimal Permissions That Does Not Inherit Principal Permissions
I am a beginner with Google GCP.
When creating a service account, the principal's permissions are inherited, and it is granted roles with overly broad capabilities. I would like to create a service account with minimal permissions that only allows adding the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot" scope. How can I achieve this?

Unclear if you've seen: https://cloud.google.com/security/products/iam

You can create a service account with minimal permissions like I have created a service account with chat apps viewer and default role will be added like Compute Engine default service account and App Engine default service account for managing the API which will be needed.
So once check what API services and products you are going to use and add them without adding excess permission. You can also use Policy Analyzer which will allow policies to find out which principals (users, service accounts, groups, and domains)have access to which Google Cloud resources. For example I have used a policy analyzer for the demo service account here are the details.

So you check whether the service account has excess permission and remove them if wanted, keep in note that some other resources will be used to use chat apps and those permissions will be needed in order to use.
